# Package 'Faker.Net 1.0.3' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm new to .NET core tools and just ran into an issue while running the following command; I can see that it's just a warning but it's not creating the "publish" folder even with "***`sudo dotnet publish -o /publish`***"

> dotnet publish -o /publish

[image]

As you can see there's no publish folders

[image]

```
/home/joel/workspace/asp (copy)/api/api.csproj : 
        warning NU1701: Package 'Faker.Net 1.0.3' was restored using '.NETFramework,
    Version=v4.6.1' 
    instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. 
This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

            Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.4.8.50001 for .NET Core
            Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

            /home/joel/workspace/asp (copy)/api/api.csproj :
         warning NU1701: Package 'Faker.Net 1.0.3' was restored using '.NETFramework,
    Version=v4.6.1' 
    instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. 
    This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
              api -> /home/joel/workspace/asp (copy)/api/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/api.dll
            /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.0.2/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/build/Microsoft.NET
        .Publish.targets(67,5): 
        error MSB3191: Unable to create directory "/publish2/". 
Access to the path '/publish2/' is denied. [/home/joel/workspace/asp (copy)/api/api.csproj]
```

Comment: Please any suggestions as to why my question got downvoted? I just need a little help and I added last blob of error to make it search friendly

Answer (score 0):

The warning shown has nothing to do with the publish problem. It just states that `Faker.Net 1.0.3` targets .NET Framework and have been resolved for that target runtime despite the application will be running on .NET Core. That is possible due to .NET Standard shim, however that library might be not fully compatible with .NET Core, so you'd rather check its compatibility with [.NET Portable Analizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/portability-analyzer)

Now the actual problem is the directory you are writing the output to is restricted for access. Thus to make it work you should get the privilege first.

try `dotnet publish -o ./publish2` (note the dot before the path)

Comment: Thanks Ivan, something is messed up with that image; the .NET Core images are using multi-arch tags which can target either Linux or Windows hosts (in my case Ubuntu) but it is possible that those images are simply not able to run on Linux for whatever reason. If I get a fresh copy of Windows 10 Pro I'll try the same commands and confirm here later whether it worked and if so then we'll know it was a host (Windows/Linux) issue - thank you